# Can .jpg have transparency?

Tags: gimp, transparency, file-format, jpg, krita

I have read everywhere that .jpg can't have transparency and you can't save it as transparent.

But I have a .jpg picture with transparency.
[Link to the picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tFy9ApXHwoBf2FIF8_l9dURioIopgpUO/view?usp=sharing)

Can anyone explain how the picture I linked has transparency despite it being in .jpg format?
And is there any way to export it with this transparency using Gimp or Krita? I tried to export using them transparency was removed.

Comment: No it can't. The format doesn't support it. The image you linked to is actually a PNG with the wrong file extension.  If you open the file in a text editor to examine it, the code starts "‰PNG".

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you. How can actual file format be found? What tools did you use?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment to tell you how to check it. Reload the page and you'll see it.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/bIHglEK) showing the code in Notepad++

Comment: Yes, thank you Billy. How Can I close question though?

Comment: I've added an answer now, so you can select it as best if you want. You might need to wait a day or two before you can choose the best answer.

Comment: I've given you some upvotes since you are new here.  Oh, Welcome to GDSE by the way!!!  ;)

Comment: thank you @BillyKerr !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The file you linked to isn't a JPG.  It's a PNG* with the wrong file extension. Maybe somebody changed it deliberately for some unknown reason, or they just saved it with the wrong file extension.

JPG is RGB only.  PNG supports RGBa (with alpha transparency). So, if you want to save it with transparency from GIMP or Krita, you need to export as PNG.

*Note: You can open the image file in a plain text editor to examine the header code.

Example below, opened in Notepad++, showing the fist line of code `‰PNG` which indicates it's actually a PNG file

[image]